# Classes endpoint not returning all of a User's Classes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

We have a situation whereby some teachers/students who log into our application are not able to retrieve the Classes they are a member of.

We call `/v1.0/education/me/classes` and it seems that if the school creates a Class through the Teams UI, the API returns the expected class. However, if the school adds a Class and Class members from outside the UI (e.g. via PowerShell or a 3rd party utility that sync with their School Management System), then the API does not return these Classes. The Classes do however appear in Teams.

All I can think is that there is some sort of hidden attributes that memberships need in order to return correctly via the API.

`/groups/<id>` endpoint returns a `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation` error.

It would appear to be a membership related issue. If the user is added as a class member through the Teams UI then the `/education/me/classes` endpoint returns their classes. If they are added via the powershell command `Add-TeamUser` then the class is not returned via the API - however it is returned via the Teams GUI.

Comment: Are you sure these were created a Classes and not simply a Group? A Class is a Group but a Group is not a Class. Can you try retrieving a failing Class using the `/groups/{id}` endpoint and add the response to your question?

Comment: Yes, If I use the `/education/classes` endpoint and browse through the list manually I can find the class. If I then use the `/education/classes/<id>/members` endpoint it does not return the teachers or students - only the user that created the class via powershell. However those classes in the Teams UI show all the members correctly!

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I've updated the original question with extra information.

Comment: The `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation` response is because you need `Groups.Read.All` in order to retrieve Groups.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur yes, the challenge is that admin consent will be required again for the additional permissions and it is challenging to get School IT departments to do that again.  (Is it essential to see the output of `/groups/{id}`?


I can retrieve the class through the `/education/classes` endpoint but the membership of that class is incorrect when read through `/education/classes/<id>/members`.

Comment: Without permission you cannot read the members. Could you please try adding the required permissions.

Comment: We aren't able to update the requested scopes without breaking things for existing users and forcing admins to grant admin_consent for our api again.

Comment: Further investigating has found that users who sync to teams via the "Schools Data Sync" utility are fine. According to the docs the differences with it are:
`Visibility option set to hidden membership`
`Custom Creation Options`
`Custom Resource Behavior Options`
`Custom extension attributes from the source data`

One or more of those things must be what the powershell command is not doing and therefore causing the graph api to not return the classes for a user.